# How to list all function calls in a class definition?

Tags: python

I have a python class which is really long and complicated (I've tried to split it in as many functions as possible) but the file ~900 rows long and it is a nightmare to keep track of all the functions.

Is there a way to list all functions in a class and checks which function calls on other functions? The file is a part of a larger user GUI so I can not run something like `CProfiler`, etc. I'm looking for something that can walk through a python file without running it, just looking through the file.

This is the [file](https://github.com/axelande/geodatafarm3/blob/master/database_scripts/mean_analyse.py), I'm aiming to get an output like this:

`__init__`:

```
 - RunAnalyseDialog()
 - AddField(parent_widget)
```

`check_consistency`:

```
 - self.fill_dict_tables()
 - etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you did document your functions, [`help(classname)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) should [help](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) you out some:

```
class A:
    """A"""


    def __init__(self,a,b):
        """Does nothing with a,b - calls self.C()"""
        self.C() 

    def C(self): 
        pass

help(A)
```

Output:

```
class A
 |  A
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  C(self)
 |  
 |  __init__(self, a, b)
 |      Does nothing with a,b - calls self.C()
```

This will only show you what you documented though - so if you did not put any "call"-documentation into your class-/function-descriptions it won't help you as much.

Comment: You are probably right.. I have put some effort in trying to tell a little bit what each function does but I've forgotten to write which other functions it calls.

Comment: I use numpy docstrings. Is there a good "header" for listing calls/dependencies? Like `Parameters`, `Returns`, `Examples` etc.

Comment: @axel_ande I doubt it - I would consider this implementation detail and not "documenting" it for the consumer to read. I tend to try to keep functions small and function names descriptive - If I want to see the "flow" I go into the code and look at it / follow it around.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Trace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html)? It might be what you ask for

```
$ python -m trace --listfuncs your_python_file.py
```

The trace module has more calls to do different things depending on what you want to list. See the link for more options

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but `trace` runs the file, I'm looking for something that does not run the file..